# QueryDSL with 'WITH RECURSIVE'

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

This Question exists in querydsl's GitHub issues.

**1. Observed vs. expected behavior**

Hi guys,
I try to get all child categories with recursive query.

**OBSERVED:**

```
Hibernate: 
    with recursive tmp1 (id, parent, name_ko) as ((select
        c.id,
        c.parent,
        c.name_ko 
    from
        car__grade c 
    where
        c.parent is null) 
union
all (select
    p.id,
    p.parent,
    p.name_ko 
from
    tmp1 
inner join
    car__grade p 
        on tmp1 = p.parent)) select
        tmp1.id,
        tmp1.name_ko 
from
    tmp1
```

all 'parent' is wrong. because it must be grade_parent_id.
however, nameKo -> name_ko changed properly.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

```
Hibernate: 
    with recursive tmp1 (id, **grade_parent_id**, name_ko) as ((select
        c.id,
        **c.grade_parent_id**,
        c.name_ko 
    from
        car__grade c 
    where
        **c.grade_parent_id** is null) 
union
all (select
    p.id,
    **p.grade_parent_id**,
    p.name_ko 
from
    tmp1 
inner join
    car__grade p 
        on **tmp1.id = p.grade_parent_id**)) select
        tmp1.id,
        tmp1.name_ko 
from
    tmp1
```

**2. Steps to reproduce**

I hope that is understandable.

// ENTITY

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(name = "car__grade")
public class Grade {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED")
  private BigInteger id;

  @Column(name = "name_ko", length = 32, nullable = false,
      columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(32)")
  private String nameKo;

  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "detail_model_id", nullable = false, updatable = false,
      columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED")
  private DetailModel detailModel;

  @QueryInit("*")
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "grade_parent_id", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED")
  private Grade parent = null;

  @Builder
  public Grade(String nameKo, DetailModel detailModel) {
    this.nameKo = nameKo;
    this.detailModel = detailModel;
  }

}
```

// REPOSITORY CODES

```
QGrade tmp1 = new QGrade("tmp1");
    QGrade c = new QGrade("c");
    QGrade p = new QGrade("p");
    PathBuilder<Grade> emp = new PathBuilder<Grade>(Grade.class, "tmp1");

    JPASQLQuery<?> q = new JPASQLQuery<>(em, MySQLTemplates.DEFAULT);
    EntityPathBase<QGrade> rec = new EntityPathBase<>(QGrade.class, "tmp1");

    SQLQuery<Grade> t =
        SQLExpressions.select(Projections.fields(Grade.class, c.id, c.parent, c.nameKo)).from(c)
            .where(c.parent.isNull());
    SQLQuery<Grade> t1 =
        SQLExpressions.select(Projections.fields(Grade.class, p.id, p.parent, p.nameKo)).from(rec)
            .innerJoin(p).on(tmp1.eq(p.parent));
    Union<Grade> union = SQLExpressions.unionAll(t, t1);

    List<Tuple> fetch = q.withRecursive(rec, c.id, c.parent, c.nameKo).as(union)
        .select(tmp1.id, tmp1.nameKo).from(rec).fetch();
```

**c.nameKo, p.nameKo changed properly, HOWEVER parent IS NOT.**

// DB (This sql is works on mysqlworkbench)

```
WITH RECURSIVE tmp1 (
    `id`,
    `grade_parent_id`,
    `name_ko`
) AS (
    SELECT  id, 
            grade_parent_id,
            name_ko
    FROM    `car__grade`
    WHERE   grade_parent_id IS NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT  r.id,
            r.grade_parent_id,
            r.name_ko
    FROM    `car__grade` AS r
    INNER JOIN tmp1 t
        ON t.id = r.grade_parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM tmp1;
```

**3. Environment**

Spring Boot 2.4.0

Querydsl version: 4.4.0

Querydsl module: querydsl-jpa

Database: MySQL8

JDK: 11

**4. Additional details**

I tested simple jpa query with same entity.

// SIMPLE QUERY AND IT'S RESULT.

```
// repo
queryFactory.select(QGrade.grade).from(QGrade.grade).where(QGrade.grade.parent.isNull())
        .fetch();

// console (it works normally especially fields 'parent'.)
Hibernate: 
    select
        grade0_.id as id1_10_,
        grade0_.detail_model_id as detail_m3_10_,
        grade0_.name_ko as name_ko2_10_,
        grade0_.grade_parent_id as grade_pa4_10_ 
    from
        car__grade grade0_ 
    where
        grade0_.grade_parent_id is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querydsl 4.x is no longer maintained, I recommend upgrading to 5.x.

Futhermore, `JPASQLQuery` has many known limitations with regard to complexer relationship joins, which is why I usually discourage the use of `JPASQLQuery`. Instead I recommend Blaze-Persistence Querydsl integrations for creating powerful JPQL queries (including ones with recursive CTE's).

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that jpa does not support recursive cte, so i currently use native query. I read about Blade-Persistence when I digged this problem, I'm not sure that this package can be used in production. any thought about stablity?

Comment: Never had any stability issues with it, nor any other folks I know from the support groups at Zulip and Slack.